# Finding the 2 closest corresponding rows to the average of the sum of multiplied values, grouped by a matching title when given an input title

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, sql-order-by, limit

I want to find the average values of a sum of multiplied values grouped by a matching title, in order to give them a corresponding rating, and then find the 2 closest to the input value.

```
SELECT titleValueAVG / 3 AS average,
       title
  FROM (
           SELECT Sum(a) AS titleValueAVG,
                  title
             FROM (
                      SELECT value * 1 AS a,
                             title
                        FROM Table1
                       WHERE type = 'A' AND 
                             contesting = 'yes'
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT value * 2,
                             title
                        FROM Table1
                       WHERE type = 'A' AND 
                             contesting = 'no'
                      UNION ALL
                      SELECT value * 3,
                             title
                        FROM Table1
                       WHERE type = 'A' AND 
                             contesting = 'undecided'
                  )
            GROUP BY title
            ORDER BY title = 'Australia' DESC,
                     ABS(titleValueAVG) - (
                                        SELECT value * 1 AS a,
                                               title
                                          FROM Table1
                                         WHERE type = 'A' AND 
                                               contesting = 'yes' AND title = 'Australia'
                                        UNION ALL
                                        SELECT value * 2,
                                               title
                                          FROM Table1
                                         WHERE type = 'A' AND 
                                               contesting = 'no' AND title = 'Australia'
                                        UNION ALL
                                        SELECT value * 3,
                                               title
                                          FROM Table1
                                         WHERE type = 'A' AND 
                                               contesting = 'undecided' AND title = 'Australia'
                                    )
       ) limit 2;
```

From an example table:

```
| Title    | Type         | Competing      | Value          |

| -------- | -------------| -------------- | -------------- |

| Australia| A            | yes            | 26             |

| Australia| A            | no             | 162            |

| Australia| A            | undecided      | 37             |

| Spain    | A            | yes            | 14             |

| Spain    | A            | no             | 101            |

| Spain    | A            | undecided      | 11             |

| Ireland  | A            | yes            | 124            |

| Ireland  | A            | no             | 62             |

| Ireland  | A            | undecided      | 9              |

| Nigeria  | C            | yes            | 4              |

| Nigeria  | C            | no             | 11             |

| Nigeria  | C            | undecided      | 7              |

| Colombia | A            | yes            | 26             |

| Colombia | A            | no             | 12             |

| Colombia | A            | undecided      | 19             |

| Turkey   | A            | yes            | 29             |

| Turkey   | A            | no             | 145            |

| Turkey   | A            | undecided      | 24             |

| Malta    | B            | yes            | 1              |

| Malta    | B            | no             | 11             |

| Malta    | B            | undecided      | 4              |

| Mexico   | A            | yes            | 74             |

| Mexico   | A            | no             | 19             |

| Mexico   | A            | undecided      | 12             |

| Slovenia | B            | yes            | 16             |

| Slovenia | B            | no             | 22             |

| Slovenia | B            | undecided      | 11             |

| Canada   | A            | yes            | 29             |

| Canada   | A            | no             | 164            |

| Canada   | A            | undecided      | 40             |

| Kenya    | C            | yes            | 8              |

| Kenya    | C            | no             | 12             |

| Kenya    | C            | undecided      | 0              |
```

So, in this example, I would like to return from an input title 'Australia:

```
| Title    | average        |

| -------- | -------------- |

| Australia| 154            |

| Canada   | 159            |

| Turkey   | 130            |
```

My attempted solution is above, I've tried multiple ways to organise the order by, which is what I think is the issue, but I can't get it to work at all. If anyone could help me fix this I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, mistake in copying because I was playing around with it trying to get it to work

Comment: Why are you dividing by 3? How do you get 461 for Australia if you divide by 3?

Comment: I was trying to integrate the average calculation into your solution from the other day for a different table's data. I kind of get how the group by and order by work now, but I'm having trouble understanding how the data is passed around and what sequence it is run in.

Comment: The initial sum(values) are multiplied, this is just an example but it's to give an overall score for each sum, as the ones in the used table could be defined as good, average, and bad. So it creates an average score for all to compare to the others.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, I'll edit it to show the correct values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT title,
         ROUND(SUM(value *
             CASE competing
               WHEN 'yes' THEN 1
               WHEN 'no' THEN 2
               WHEN 'undecided' THEN 3
             END
         ) / 3.0) average
  FROM tablename
  WHERE type = 'A'
  GROUP BY title
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY title = 'Australia' DESC,
         ABS(average - (SELECT average FROM cte WHERE title = 'Australia'))
LIMIT 3;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c8c8084d8339b7f05dd9245638124aba).